# ssrs recursive drilldown breaks paging

Tags: recursion, reporting-services, paging, drilldown

I have a recursive drill down on my `ssrs` report.  It is something like `EmployeeID` to `ManagerID`.  When I do that, it is breaking paging when I try to render as `Expand All`.  The problem is this report can have over 100 pages of data and it is not rendering with paging when I try to expand all the rows.

Looking at the example data, expand all will look like the what is shown.
If recursive Parent is on, then I only start with 1 row of data.
When I turn off visibility, then all the rows will expand and it will not go to the next page.

Example Data:

Level       Name       Position
 - 1           Bob                President
   - 2         Andrew     VP
    - 3        Dew        Director
     ...
   - 2         Adam      VP
    - 3       Russell    Director

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not rendering with paging"?  As in, you get one page of partial output, and the rest is "missing", or you get everything on a single page?  And what format are you rendering into?

Comment: ah sorry. So when I try to display all the record at once.  It tries to load everything on one page. Data is not missing or anything like that.  When that recursive data is massive, the report just crashes from running out of memory.  I am just displaying the report on the internet explorer.